# Are there other ways of viewing size of iOS apps without jailbreaking?

Tags: iphone, ios, filesystems, size

is there a way to view a list of apps on my iPad and iPhone and see how much total space they're taking up? When I look at the apps through iTunes and sort them by size, it doesn't take into consideration the data stored with those apps.

For example, in iTunes I see the New Yorker app as "9MB", but I have multiple issues of the magazine downloaded and one of them alone is over 125MB large.

Comment: Are you talking about how to programmatically get the size of your app and its associated files, or are you just trying to access that information for all apps installed?  This doesn't seem to be a programming related question.  Enlighten me if I am making an incorrect assumption.

Comment: I'd say he's asking how to find out which apps take up most space on his device so when he runs low he can delete those. i.e I'd say off topic.

Comment: please make an "Enhancement Request" to [Apple feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html). This way, if enough people makes these requests, Apple would add them in future release. To get things moving you could also make the request to the creator of the [The New Yorker Magazine](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/the-new-yorker-magazine/id370614765?mt=8) app, Condé Nast Digital.

Answer (score 1):

If I have 200 e-books, then the size of those e-books does not and should not affect the size of iBooks (or any other reader). It is not the size of the app that you are after, but rather the size of all the other data you download.